# Same pattern does not apply to duplicate layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I've made some random text in photoshop. I want to make that text look like mirror image, like in picture below:

[image]

But the problem that I'm facing is, that I'm using pattern overlay effect on my primary text. And if I transform this text to vertical image, there is a whole new color applied to that mirrored text. Please take a look what I mean:

[image]

So my question is: How do I apply same pattern color as the first layer? So my mirror image will be exactly the same as original image (except flipped vertical)

Comment: I’m not entirely sure if I understand the problem. But what I would try is adding the pattern effect and then converting the Layer to a Smart Object (Right Click the layer > …). Then duplicate it and flip it. If you want to change the pattern just Doubleclick the Smart Object.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do whatever you did with "Hello"
2. Select all layers except the background layer.
3. Turn layers  into smart object.
4. Duplicate the newly created smart object. Let's call it HelloB
5. FLIP HelloB vertically. Do not rotate it. flip it, then position it underneath Hello.
6. Set transparencies and stuff to HelloB.
7. For that vanishing effect, i would apply a layer mask to HelloB and use a big basic brush with 0 hardness, then paint the vanishing portions off. There are several other ways to do this. It's your call.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out the following:

1. Have just 'Hello' written as a text layer and apply the pattern overlay as you want to.
2. Duplicate the text layer
3. Free transform it to rotate it 180 degrees
4. Rasterize the new rotated layer
5. Finally, play with a foreground to transparent gradient on it, or maybe its opacity and blend mode.

This approach might seem amateur, but you'l easily get what you are looking for.